# Only the first if statement is executing in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have two jQuery if statements that perform a remove() from a submenu.  They work fine if there is only one true statement, but if there is an id1 & an id2 on the page, only the first if triggers.

```
if ($('#id1').length==0) { $('#submenu li').eq(2).remove();}

if( $('#id2').length==0) { $('#submenu li').eq(3).remove();}
```

Updated: Answered below, it was a simple indexing issue where reversing the removal order from the array worked fine.

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide the HTML markup where the question is?

Comment: Are your IDs inside the `submenu`? As you remove those `li`s you might be changing the indexing.

Comment: I would think that if there is both an id1 and id2, neither if statement would trigger, since both conditions would evaluate to false...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an indexing issue. By removing the 2nd element, the 3rd element now moves into the 2nd position. You then try to remove what used to be the 3rd element, but there's nothing at that index anymore.

To solve this, try removing the elements in reverse order, from highest index to lowest.

```
if( $('#id2').length==0) { $('#submenu li').eq(3).remove();}

if ($('#id1').length==0) { $('#submenu li').eq(2).remove();}
```

Comment: You're making quite an assumption about the HTML here...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan no I'm not. The OP is removing items from the same global `#submenu` selector so it's just an indexing issue.

Comment: There's no indication, in the question itself, of whether the second removal fails or not, just that "only the first if triggers". It could be that there is an element with the ID "id2" in the HTML.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan there absolutely is indication of that. Look at the `$('#submenu li')` query. That's a global query, NOT a sub-selection so they're the same group of elements. Next, the OP said if the first one fires, the second one doesn't. I assumed it was based on the order of removal affecting the indexing.

Comment: Obviously I'm not getting through, and it's irrelevant anyway. You were the FGITW, guessed correctly, and won the kewpie doll.